# multiple same result occur

Tags: python, loops

I am finding Monisen Number and got the result. However, the same result will come out multiple times.

Code:

```
for p in range(2, 10):
    if p > 1:
        for i in range(2, p):
            if (p % i) != 0:
                m = (2 ** p) - 1
                if m % i != 0:
                    print(format(m), 'is Monisen Number')
                # elif m % i != 0:
                else:
                    break
            else:
                break


Result:
7 is Monisen Number
31 is Monisen Number
31 is Monisen Number
31 is Monisen Number
127 is Monisen Number
127 is Monisen Number
127 is Monisen Number
127 is Monisen Number
127 is Monisen Number
511 is Monisen Number
```

Process finished with exit code 0

Let a result only come out one time.

Comment: What is the question here? Why it happens? Try printing also `p` and `i` with each result to understand what is going on.

Comment: The first Monisen number (Mersenne prime) is 3

Answer (score 0):

Add a `break` after print statement:

```
for p in range(2, 10):
    if p > 1:
        for i in range(2, p):
            if (p % i) != 0:
                m = (2 ** p) - 1
                if m % i != 0:
                    print(format(m), 'is Monisen Number')
                    break
                else:
                    break
            else:
                break

#output
7 is Monisen Number
31 is Monisen Number
127 is Monisen Number
511 is Monisen Number
```

Comment: Are you sure 511 is a Monisen number?